# capistrano-resque fails during start up

Tags: capistrano

This may be a specific issue with the production environment as I can successfully deploy to our staging machine. Basically, I get an error running the command:

```
cd /home/my-service/git/my-api/current && ( export RBENV_ROOT="/usr/local/rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.4.0" ; /usr/bin/env nohup /usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake RACK_ENV=production RAILS_ENV=production  QUEUE="*" PIDFILE=/home/my-service/git/my-api/shared/tmp/pids/resque_work_1.pid BACKGROUND=yes VERBOSE=1 INTERVAL=5 environment resque:work >> log/resque.log 2>> log/resque.log )
```

I changed the service and API names in the above. In any case, the command gets an exit status of 1 when run through capistrano-resque, but logging in and pasting the command works. The resque workers start, I get a log file, and a PID file.

The primary difference between the staging and production environments is that the former is hosted on AWS and the latter by another company that provides HIPPA compliance. As I said, it is possible that there is something in the configuration of the latter that causes this, but I'm looking for any ideas I can find.